# UISearchBar - what is "search results button" for?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, search, uisearchbar

(Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283058), but I figured I could try again, since that one wasn't answered...)

The UISearchBar on the iPhone has an option showsSearchResultsButton. When you turn it on, it shows a button with horizontal lines inside the search bar, and you can implement a callback that will be called when the user presses it.

The thing is, I can't find a single place on the Internet where it says what the intended purpose of this button is. I know I could make it do anything, but I'd like to know what it's actually for. Should it show a history of searches, or all items without filtering, or what?

Comment: That other question is about how to use it, your question is about what it's for. That's not exactly duplicate, so you might want to remove that line before this gets flagged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply to show search results when tapped.

Where Apple uses this is in their iPad App Store application. If you go to the Categories tab you'll see various app categories. Search for an item, you'll get a list of results, and when you press "Done" you are shown the categories screen again. Your previous search term is still listed in the search field, but now the Search Results Button appears in the field. After tapping this, a UIPopOver is displayed, showing a text list of the results from your last search.

Comment: It took me a moment to figure out what was the difference between this and just clicking on the text field. When I click on the text field, I automatically enter the "edit mode", I see the keyboard, gray overlay and so on. When I click "search results", I just see the list (which can be longer since there's no keyboard). So this is intended for when I want to pick another result without changing the previously typed query. Makes sense, thanks.