# UITableView is hidden by a new UITableView when displaying search

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a view, containing a UITableView (myTableView) and some buttons. myTableView also has a searchbar. The moment I start searching, myTableView is covered by a new tableview with the search results. Since myTableView is only covering half the screen, and the new tableview covers the entire screen, I have a problem. How can I set the new UITableView to only cover the same part of the screen as myTableView?

Comment: Please tell us what platform you are developing on.  This is IOS, but are you on a phone, tablet, or what?

Comment: This is an universal application, iPhone and iPad. The problem applies for both platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you may be using UISearchDisplayController, which contains a UITableView to display search results on.  If you want to roll your own, just use a UISearchBar and its delegate methods to populate your own table instead of the included results view.

Comment: Thanks. I have added UISearchBarDelegate to the interface and set the searchBar delegate to self.Still, I am not sure how to use the UISearchBar and its delegate methods to populate"myTableView". At least, I can not find any protocols in apple documentation that includes populating a tableview. Can you please give me a short lesson?

Comment: The basic gist is using the UISearchBarDelegate to catch the query string with the textDidChange delegate method, and from here perform your search.  With the data you get back, populate the same NSArray you use for the table view normally and run -[UITableView reloadData] to use the new data.  Try [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283058/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-the-uisearchbardelegate-showssearchresultsbutton-at) for reference.